# Why Merger Join need sorted Input in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In SSIS we have merge join which is always enforced to the user to get the sorted input.

But in SQL server we have merge, it's not required any sorted.

kindly explain to me why merge need sorted input.

Thanks,

Praveenkumar.K

Answer (score 1):

The merge join works by simultaneously reading and comparing the two sorted inputs one row at a time.  At each step, we compare the next row from each input.  If the rows are equal, we output a joined row and continue.  If the rows are not equal, we discard the lesser of the two inputs and continue.  Since the inputs are sorted, we know that we are discarding a row that is less than any of the remaining rows in either input and, thus, can never join.

We can express the algorithm in pseudo-code as:

```
get first row R1 from input 1
get first row R2 from input 2
while not at the end of either input
    begin
        if R1 joins with R2
            begin
                return (R1, R2)
                get next row R2 from input 2
            end
        else if R1 < R2
            get next row R1 from input 1
        else
            get next row R2 from input 2
    end
```

References:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191426(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Thank you Thangadurai.B, Good explanation.Very Helpfull.

Comment: Welcome  bro @PraveenKumar