# SSIS Merge Join not matching all rows on inner join

Tags: merge, ssis, inner-join

I have two tables in Azure SQL Server which, when I query directly using [SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpH3z.png) on the 'GroupID', gives me the expected output of 5,698 rows.

However, when I use **Merge Join** in SSIS
[image: Dataflow] only 4,832 rows are merged using the **inner join**.

I've checked the metadata types (both are DT_I4 and Sorted, Position 1):

> "Name"    "Data Type" "Precision" "Scale" "Length"    "Code Page" "Sort Key
> Position" "Comparison Flags"  "Source Component"
>
> "GroupID" "DT_I4" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" ""  "INDEX"
>
> "Name"    "Data Type" "Precision" "Scale" "Length"    "Code Page" "Sort Key
> Position" "Comparison Flags"  "Source Component"
>
> "GroupID" "DT_I4" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" ""  "ASSETS by .........."

as many posts talk about data type inconsistency or trying to join on strings. I have checked that the source data results in a full inner join but I just can't see what could be causing the SSIS inner join to not work as expected.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: So you have an inner join that is dropping expected values. The next step is to identify a value from the left that should match, but does not match a value on the right. Then a value on the right that should have a match but does not. Finally, confirm the values that do match are matching as expected. From what you show, it seems you are using the component correctly so that leaves us to assume that the data does not match your assumption.

Comment: Is this an ADO.NET or OLEDB source on both?

Comment: Yes that's correct re dropping values. The data source is OLE and destination ADO.

I have decided to not use the the Merge Join and simply use a SQL Command in the data source to do the inner join which I know works. Maybe not the perfect solution but unblocks the project to move forward. Thanks for commenting  billinkc

Answer (score 0):

The workaround to this problem (which I have not solved) is to replace the **Merge Join** with a SQL Command: INNER JOIN within the OLE DB Source.

[image]

I suppose this is OK within the same DB but if you have different sources then it would not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The generalized solution would be to use a Lookup component if the match condition is 0 to 1. A person has one death date - it might not exist but it only happens once<sup>*</sup>

If the match condition is 0 to many, then a Merge Join makes sense. A key component to a Merge Join however is that both data sets must be sorted. If you do not have an explicit `ORDER BY` in the two sources (or add an explicit Sort to *both* paths before the Merge Join), then that would explain your experience here.

- [Why Merger Join need sorted Input in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821348/why-merger-join-need-sorted-input-in-ssis)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/sort-data-for-the-merge-and-merge-join-transformations